# Tools to do Semantic Anotation on 3d CAD Models

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, 3d-object-detection

I am trying to do Segmentation on my custom dataset consisting of 3D CAD Models.
However, I am not able to find the proper tools to generate my dataset for Segmentation.

I am able to find the existing dataset with segmentation information, but am not able to find any information on how to create one for our own CAD Models.

I need to train the model on my custom dataset hence creating one.
I will really appreciate any help that is provided.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to update that I was able to perform annotation on the 3d models by using following tools

- [Semantic Segmentation Editor](https://github.com/Hitachi-Automotive-And-Industry-Lab/semantic-segmentation-editor)
- Blender
- FreeCAD

Blender and FreeCAD are easy to use, but needs some postprocessing to get the annotations right especially on point cloud data, whereas Semantic Segmentation Editor can be used to directly annotate the point cloud but that stuff is not easy.